# Filter many to many set from models instance

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a product model that has tags, the tags can be in multiple languages. when I get a instance of the product, i have a `product.tags` manager.

I was wondering if there was a way to filter the tags connected to the product **instance**, that when I pass it to the **serializer**, i would only get the tags in a single language with the serializer output.

```py
class Product(models.Model):
   ...
   tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
   ...


class Tag(models.Model)
   text = models.CharField(max_length=32)
   language = models.CharField(max_length=2)


class ProductSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
   tags = TagSerializer(many=True)
   ...
```

I am able to filter them manually then add them to the data response, like so:

```py
tags_query = product.tags.filter(language=lang)
tag_serializer = TagSerializer(lang, many=True)
```

but I was wondering if this can be done through the serializers?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that through the serializers.
You can do like this:

```
tags_query = product.tags.filter(language=lang)
tag_serializer = TagSerializer(tags_query, many=True)
```

Comment: Yeah, i ended up down exactly this, still feels a bit hacky to me, i would rather have it all done from the serializer.
Thanks.